# jquery, javascript - how to remove this parameter from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl

I have some coding and already pushed this into a variable. I would like to remove it and reinsert another value. Please note that I am programming a lot of the coding with perl. I would like to remove menu_mode value. Any tips would be a great since javascript/jquery are a new language to me.

```
    print qq|
               \$("#extractparam").click(function () {
                   \$("#grapharea").html(" ");|;

    foreach my $num (1 .. $count)
    {
        if ($num eq 1)
        {
            print STDOUT qq|var params = \$("#volt$num").serializeArray();|;
        } else
        {
            print STDOUT qq|var volt$num = \$("#volt$num").serializeArray();|;
            print STDOUT qq|params = \$.merge(params, volt$num);|;
        }
    }

print qq|          params.push({ name: 'menu_mode', value: '3C-extractparameters' });
                   \$.get("./scripts/banana_extract.cgi", params, function(data){ \$("#paramselection").html(data) });

                   // would like to remove the menu_mode value

                   params.push({ name: 'menu_mode', value: '3D-extractparameters' });
                   \$.get("./scripts/banana_extract.cgi", params, function(data){ \$("#graphoptionselection").html(data) });

                    \$("#extractparam").removeAttr('style');
                    \$("#Execute_Button").css("background-color","lightblue");

               });
```

Comment: And that ^^ is why I don't use Perl for web stuff. Dang that's nasty looking.

Comment: I love Perl, and I love JavaScript, but don't mix them like this. The only JS that Perl should output directly should be the data (using `JSON::Any` for example). Manipulate the data with Perl before doing that. Manipulate the data with JavaScript after that. Don't manipulate the JavaScript logic with Perl - that way leads to code that is hard to read and maintain.

Comment: @sholsinger — Don't blame the language for what a programmer does with it.

Comment: @sholsinger, you can do ridiculous stuff like mixing Javascript and server-side code in any language. That doesn't mean Perl people condone those sorts of shenanigans.

Comment: any advice on how to better integrate the two? using print << tags?

Comment: @Gordon, *don't* integrate the two. Use your script to return JSON data which is used client-side by the Javascript. And use a templating system like Template Toolkit or HTML::Template to render your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want this:

```
params.pop();
```

That'll remove the last element from the array (the one you just pushed).